# Como subir una imagen con expo-image-picker - React Native con EXPO

Tags: reactjs, imagen, react-native, expo

Estoy intentando subir una imágen de la galería de un dispositivo móvil android.

Cuando intento sacar por consola la uri o el nombre de la imagen seleccionada no tengo problema. Pero si le hago fetch a uri me devuelve un pantallazo con el error: value.hasOwnProperty('tag') is undefined.

```
  const uploadImage = async (uri, nameImage) => {
    const response = await fetch(uri);
    console.log(response);
  };
```

Dejo aquí una captura:
[image: Pantallazo recibido del console.log(response)]
Codigo completo del componente.

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Image } from "react-native";
import { Avatar } from "react-native-elements";
import * as firebase from "firebase";
import * as Permissions from "expo-permissions";
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";

export default function InfoUser(props) {
  const {
    userInfo: { uid, displayName, email, photoURL }
  } = props;

  const changeAvatar = async () => {
    const resultPermission = await Permissions.askAsync(
      Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL
    );
    const resultPermissionCamera =
      resultPermission.permissions.cameraRoll.status;

    if (resultPermissionCamera == "denied") {
      console.log("Es necesario aceptar los permisos de la galería.");
    } else {
      const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        allowsEditing: true,
        aspect: [4, 3]
      });

      if (result.cancelled) {
        console.log("has cancelado la galeria");
      } else {
        uploadImage(result.uri, uid);
      }
    }
  };

  const uploadImage = async (uri, nameImage) => {
    const response = await fetch(uri);
    console.log(response);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.viewUserInfo}>
      <Avatar
        rounded
        size="xlarge"
        showEditButton
        onEditPress={changeAvatar}
        containerStyle={styles.userInfoAvatar}
        overlayContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#fff" }}
        source={{
          uri: photoURL
            ? photoURL + "?type=large"
            : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ecodeas-5142d.appspot.com/o/UsersAvatars%2FDefaultAvatar%2Favatar.png?alt=media&token=607d825f-80cc-4d73-b70e-637487b45a02"
        }}
      />
      <View style={styles.viewUserName}>
        <Text style={styles.displayName}>
          {displayName ? displayName : "anonimo"}
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.displayEmail}>{email ? email : "sin email"}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  viewUserInfo: {
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    paddingTop: 30,
    paddingBottom: 30
  },
  userInfoAvatar: {
    marginRight: 20,
    borderWidth: 5,
    borderColor: "#CDCDCD",
    borderStyle: "solid"
  },
  displayName: {
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    color: "#2BA418"
  },
  displayEmail: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: "#2BA418"
  },
  viewUserName: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginTop: 10
  }
});
```

El objetivo final es subirlo a firebase storage pero esto no me permite seguir.

Estoy utilizando React Native con EXPO y el imagepicker que uso es Expo-image-picker, una dependencia obtenida con yarn.

Esoy comenzando con la programación y llevo además muy poco con react native. Por si pongo algún disparate...

Les agradezco cualquier tipo de ayuda, un saludo a todos.

Comment: ¿Has probado poner la petición dentro de un try/catch? al parecer es el console.log con el response el que está generando el error, a ver si te amplia la info.

Answer (score 0):

para poder subir la imagen desde expo a tu servidor, debes convertirla a formdata y luego proceder a subir, aquí un ejemplo:

```
      let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
        allowsEditing: false,
        aspect: [4, 3],
        quality: 0.6,
      });
      if (!result.cancelled) {
        const data = new FormData();
        let uriParts = result.uri.split('.');
        let fileType = uriParts[uriParts.length - 1];

        data.append('images', {
          name: `photo.${fileType}`,
          type: `image/${fileType}`,
          uri: result.uri,
        });
```